# Synchronizing resource access

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, thread-safety

Here's my problem:

I have an "engine" thread, which continuously uses a resource (owned by the engine). Other threads might want to access the resource, in which case they should tell the engine to pause and wait until they are done. However, I'm not sure what is the best way to implement that with the available synchronization primitives (assuming Windows, though in perspective I might need to support other platforms as well).

In the simplest case, the engine would run a loop that enters a critical section, does some work, and leaves the section. However, since critical sections are not first-come-first-serve, other threads trying to enter that section might get stuck forever.

In my previous solution, I created an event object that is normally signalled, and the engine would wait on that event every time before entering the critical section. Another thread would reset the event, then enter the section, do some work, leave the section and signal the event. However, this would not work if I have more than one (other) thread trying to access the resource, as the event object does not have a counter.

I could simply use an integer counter and increment/decrement it with interlocked operations, but then the engine thread would have to wait until the counter is zero with a loop, which is wasting execution time. A "hybrid" approach using both an integer counter, an event and a critical section seems too complex to be the right solution.

Comment: Are you saying the engine has an infinite amount of work to do on the resource?

Comment: Yes; in my previous project it was running a render loop, and other threads paused it to modify the "state"; this time its an interpreter executing a script.

Comment: You might try using a Mutex. My understanding is that they're more fair than critical sections, although still not strictly FIFO.

Answer (score 0):

I think probably the best solution is a thread-safe counter with a "wait until zero" operation. The engine operates as follows:

1. Acquire the lock.
2. If the counter is non-zero, release the lock, wait for the counter to be zero, and go to step 1.
3. Do some work.
4. Go to step 2.

To access the object:

1. Increment the counter.
2. Acquire the lock.
3. Access the object.
4. Release the lock.
5. Decrement the counter.

Comment: Yep this is what I was thinking; however, how would I wait until the counter is zero without running a simple `while(c>0) ;` loop?

Comment: You have to implement the waitable counter. One simple way is to use a lock and an event. When you decrement the counter, if you decrement it to zero, unblock the event before you release the lock.

Comment: So basically the last solution I mentioned, that involves a counter, an event and a critical section? I was really hoping there is a solution that doesn't involve all three, but I guess that will do.

Comment: I'm sure you can probably find ways to get rid of something, but they'll be more complicated and harder to understand.

Comment: I'd use an atomic counter and a `std::condition_variable_any` together with a `mutex`